# How to set BITNAMI_CONTAINER_PATH for drupal-bitnami stack on OSX

Tags: macos, drupal, bitnami

Downloaded drupal-bitnami stack from apple store on MAC OSX. After installation while trying to start apache server there is a failure as many configuration files including httpd.conf have reference to some variable BITNAMI_CONTAINER_PATH. Does anyone know how and where it should be set.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I deleted following folder:

/Users//Library/Containers/com.bitnami.drupal/

This folder contains automatically created configuration files. After deleting the folder it got created again when I started Apache from UI